# Javascript sort descending and loop

Tags: javascript

I have this array. I don't know how to sort users array descending by count, and then loop this array. This is in javascript.

```
    users[23423423] = { count: 5, name: "Bla Bla" }
    users[32432234] = { count: 15, name: "Etc Etc" }
    users[87686786] = { count: 30, name: "Jason" }
    users[54633683] = { count: 1, name: "Party" }
    users[68345521] = { count: 23, name: "Another name" }
```

`users[key]` - key is the facebook id.

How can I sort users array descending by count?
How can I loop this array in javascript like foreach in php? Thank you.

Comment: Arrays don't typically have arbitrary key-value associations; array keys are typically supposed to be contiguously numeric. That's not a (typical) array.

Comment: I tried this: 

users.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.count) - parseFloat(b.count);
});

but nothing happens

Comment: Ok but when I create array, ex: i have this facebook id 2 times users[68345521] and I have to add to count

Comment: Is `users` really an array, or is it an object whose keys are the facebook IDs?

Comment: It is an object, yes there are facebook id's

Comment: Objects don't have a `.sort` method. "Nothing happens" is a bit misleading. *Errors* should be happening.

Comment: var users = new Array(); this is how I use users, but is object. why? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Object property doesn't have any order instead sort the property name array and fetch element in the sorted array order. Where you can use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method for sorting the property name array.

```js
var users = {};

users[23423423] = {
  count: 5,
  name: "Bla Bla"
}
users[32432234] = {
  count: 15,
  name: "Etc Etc"
}
users[87686786] = {
  count: 30,
  name: "Jason"
}
users[54633683] = {
  count: 1,
  name: "Party"
}
users[68345521] = {
  count: 23,
  name: "Another name"
}

var keys = Object.keys(users).sort(function(j, k) {
  return users[j].count - users[k].count;
})

console.log(keys);

console.log(keys.map(function(v) {
  return users[v];
}));
```

Comment: My arrays appear as Objects. I don't know why